# Cannot nest placeholder captures for the same placeholder'

Tags: zend-framework2

i am making an ajax call to the controller, i dont know wants going wrong and this error is coming. 
can someone explain this error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\View\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Cannot nest placeholder captures for the same placeholder' in E:\xampp\htdocs\xnspy-web-app\xnspy-cp\vendor\ZF2\View\Helper\Placeholder\Container\AbstractContainer.php:141 Stack trace: #0 E:\xampp\htdocs\xnspy-web-app\xnspy-cp\module\Application\view\partial\global-head.phtml(5): Zend\View\Helper\Placeholder\Container\AbstractContainer->captureStart() #1 E:\xampp\htdocs\xnspy-web-app\xnspy-cp\vendor\ZF2\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer.php(506): include('E:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 E:\xampp\htdocs\xnspy-web-app\xnspy-cp\vendor\ZF2\View\Helper\Partial.php(61): Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->render('partial/global-...', NULL) #3 [internal function]: Zend\View\Helper\Partial->__invoke('partial/global-...') #4 E:\xampp\htdocs\xnspy-web-app\xnspy-cp\vendor\ZF2\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer.php(399): call_user_func_array(Object(Zend\View\Helper\Partial), Array) #5 E:\xampp\htdocs\xnspy-web-app\xnspy-cp\module\Application\view\layout\ajax-layout.phtml(3): Z in E:\xampp\htdocs\xnspy-web-app\xnspy-cp\vendor\ZF2\View\Helper\Placeholder\Container\AbstractContainer.php on line 141

Comment: Please add some code from your _ajax-layout.phtml_ file where the error occurs

Comment: thanks for your concern ... i have solved it

Answer (score 0):

This error comes when u open capturestart two times in a row

placeholder('script')->captureStart(); ?>
placeholder('script')->captureStart(); ?>

eleminate one and problem is solved.